# Mathjax rendered symbols disappear with Google Chrome Hardware Acceleration

Tags: google-chrome, wikipedia, mathjax, hardware-acceleration

In Wikipedia, when looking in pages using Mathjax rendered formulas, Google Chrome hardware acceleration seem to mess up the displaying of some small symbols like the minus sign, example:

[Wikipedia Gaussian Integral page with hardware acceleration ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG6TO.png)

This is instead if hardware acceleration is turned off:

[Wikipedia Gaussian Integral page with hardware acceleration OFF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CImVw.png)

Any solution other than turning hw acceleration off? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome that's been fixed recently (Chrome 88), cf. the discussion at https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2612

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @PeterKrautzberger

> It's a bug in Chrome that's been fixed recently (Chrome 88), cf. the
> discussion at github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2612